# how to add performance checks for Web Vitals scores in E2E testing with different network conditions using playwright

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright, playwright-test

I want to check the web performances scores like **First Contentful Paint (FCP)**, **Time to Interactive (TTI)**, and other web vitals score using playwright and also want to check **network throttling** in **different conditions like slow 3g** how can that be achieved using **playwright**.